# Why is the blender exchange option missing from the export tab in makehuman?

Tags: import, makehuman

In all the tutorials for makehuman I watched on youtube, on the export tab, there is an option to export as blender exchange. However, in my makehuman, that option doesn't exist. I remember a long time ago, I exported my makehuman models as blender exchange before, but that was an old version. I don't know where that option went. My makehuman version is the newest one (I just redownloaded it). Here are some screenshots:

My makehuman:

[image: Notice that there's no blender exchange option on the left!]

Youtube tutorial:

[image: Notice that there is a blender option.]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .mhx export code  wasn't included in MakeHuman because it's quite heavy. You have to download and install it separately. Follow the instructions and you should be fine.

https://bitbucket.org/Diffeomorphic/mhx2-makehuman-exchange